# How to delete relationship between 2 nodes on Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Neo4j graph database.

I want to disconnect 2 nodes if they are connected by any relationship.

How to do that ?

Comment: please show some research and if you use any orm share your entity and repository classes

Answer (score 1):

Get your nodes somehow. This example assumes you have an Id parameter on the nodes. (but you can use any parameter to get a match)

match (n:SomeLabel)-[r]-(m:AnotherLabel) where m.Id =1, n.Id =2 delete r